# Unable to list new files on a cifs share with ls *

Tags: unix, cifs, netapp, hp-ux

I have an old HP-UX system running version 11.11, it has a cifs mount configured to a netapp filer.

In the past several days we've been seeing some odd behaviour for the share where files can be created & accessed if the full path is used, but wildcard listings are failing. Remounting the share seems to correct this behaviour. A practical example:

```
cd /path/in/myshare
touch newfile.txt
ls * #finds nothing
ls newfile.txt #finds file
umount /sharepath 
mount -a 
ls * #finds the file
```

Anyone have any guesses as to what's causing this odd behaviour?

Comment: What has changed on this system recently?  It may be trivial, but I would start looking in your /etc on the HP-UX system for any conf file that has changed recently.  Has anything changed on the Windows system you are trying to mount from?  Can you experiment with another Windows system, perhaps one that has been newly built?  Finally, has anything changed on your network configuration?  There are so many factors that can affect a CIFS or Samba mount.

Comment: Something else to look at would be permissions.  One thing I know is that Windows loves to dominate permissions on whatever mount it is attached to - no matter the host OS.  This was much worse using Services for Unix and mounting from Unix to Windows, but it can go the other way as well.  Be sure to double check your permissions on the files you are trying to access.

Comment: The mount was moved from a windows fileshare to a netapp cifs share (permissions retained intact) a couple of months ago. It was fine for approximately 6 weeks after the move, however in the last week or so we've experienced issues twice.

Comment: 1. Are you running anti-virus on the netapp filer?
2. Can you tell me what your inode usage looks like on the HP-UX side?
(Run "df -i")

Comment: No anti-virus on the filer. df -i output:
/path/to/share (remoteserver:/share) : 551502400 total i-nodes
                                                   1000000 free i-nodes
                                                  550502400 used i-nodes

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I believe old pointers/soft links were broken or corrupted when the mount was moved, resulting in false pointers.

Remounting would update the paths allowing the wildcards to work properly again.

Comment: The problem has recurred a couple of times - with a remount 'fixing' it each time. The issue you describe would be a one off ?

Comment: Yeah... so, I am as useful as a football bat for you brother. Good luck. Nothing else comes to mind, unless there are some sort of connectivity issues.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can occur on Windows clients as well when running a buggy version of SMB2. Force the client to speak SMB3 and see if the problem goes away.

Find you samba configguration

```
$ sudo vi smb.conf
```

Change the minimum protocol to SMB3

> min protocol = SMB3

NOTE: You might need to update HP-UX, see bulletin:

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c05121842

Comment: That sounds plausible. I'll give it try and see. Unfortunately updates to the OS are out of the question as it's a legacy system running ancient ERP software that doesn't work on more recent versions. Thankfully it's being phased out but in the meantime...